# PHP Paypal Integration with existing cart and multiple sellers

Tags: php, paypal

I've been going round in circles looking at Paypal's convoluted API docs trying to work out exactly what I need to be doing.

I have a PHP website that has its own cart already developed, and now I need to integrate Paypal with it.
What I want it to do is allow buying multiple items from multiple sellers and dealing with them all in one transaction, while allowing the oppertunity to adjust postage cost once the buyers address is confirmed.

So far I've gotten a barebones single amount single seller transaction nearly working, using PHP from Paypal's integration wizard, however I'm not having much luck getting that working properly (or understanding what's going on) - I've given up trying to debug that and am currently poking bits of the API on the sandbox to see if I can decipher what I actually need to do.

I'd ideally like to see a good how-to guide from someone who has already done what I'm doing, or a link to some further reading that is less vague and more example-rich than paypal's docs.

I'm sure it's not just me but I have a hard time reading a description of what some code *should* do compared to reading the code itself.

Any nudges in the right direction are much appreciated

Comment: Is the cash-money expected to be in one PayPal seller account, or multiple PayPal seller accounts?

Comment: multiple seller accounts. the site itself won't have an account per se, unless requried to use the API (still hazy on that part)

Comment: From what I have read, each seller would need his own API credentials, and you would need to switch between API credentials with each transaction. Hopefully, someone can verify this for you or offer an alternative.

Comment: thanks for looking, I appreciate the effort even if it's not the answer i want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using the PayPal NVP / SOAP API?

What you describe seems to be what the [PayPal Adaptive Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) ([documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf)) tries to accomplish, I've never messed with it personally but I'm pretty sure that's what you are looking for:

- Send simple payments to a single recipient.
- Make split payments to multiple recipients.
- Send chained payments to multiple recipients, one after the other, each of which can take a cut of the payment.
- Make parallel payments to multiple recipients at the same time.

Comment: thanks for that, I've made a little headway but the rest remains to be seen. I can get back to my code on Monday, will update / conclude then.

Comment: i'm looking through these docs now, I haven't got much further but marking as correct as this does answer my question, thankyou.

Comment: for anyone else who happens on this:
I've finally made some progress and gotten parallel payments working on my site. To do this, I read the docs (they suck) and used the integration wizard paypal provide, here: https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/
BEWARE the code they give you for pre-approval (that i'm not using) is broken. If you use that, look carefully at the $returnUrl and $cancelUrl vars as they are referred to later as $returnURL and $cancelURL, making the code fail every time. Thanks paypal!